# join two .csv files according to reference column in pandas

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, pandas

I have 2 files of different size (customer_id is not in same order in both files):

[image]

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

id    name    country   town     customer_id
xxxx  Anna     UK       London   sahdghkl
yyyy  Maria    USA      Huston   avrnnfgs
cccc  Peter    FR       Paris    eesfawsd

data2 = pd.read_csv('data2.csv')

customer_id  card_id   bank   date
sahdghkl     5975845   aaaaa  20000101
avrnnfgs     1122255   bbbbb  20010101
eesfawsd     3366552   ccccc  20020101
```

I want to get the output:

```
result
id    name    country   town     customer_id  card_id   bank   date
xxxx  Anna     UK       London   sahdghkl     5975845   aaaaa  20000101 
yyyy  Maria    USA      Huston   avrnnfgs     1122255   bbbbb  20010101
cccc  Peter    FR       Paris    eesfawsd     3366552   ccccc  20020101
```

Comment: Do you have "one-to-one" relation in these datasets?

Comment: try `data1.merge(data2, on='customer_id')`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use pandas.merge

## Create the dataframes:

```
temp = u"""id    name    country   town     customer_id
xxxx  Anna     UK       London   sahdghkl
yyyy  Maria    USA      Huston   avrnnfgs
cccc  Peter    FR       Paris    eesfawsd"""
data = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), header=0,delim_whitespace = 1)

temp = u"""customer_id  card_id   bank   date
sahdghkl     5975845   aaaaa  20000101
avrnnfgs     1122255   bbbbb  20010101
eesfawsd     3366552   ccccc  20020101"""
data2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), header=0,delim_whitespace = 1)

df = pd.merge(data,data2,on = 'customer_id')
print df

     id   name country    town customer_id  card_id   bank      date
0  xxxx   Anna      UK  London    sahdghkl  5975845  aaaaa  20000101
1  yyyy  Maria     USA  Huston    avrnnfgs  1122255  bbbbb  20010101
2  cccc  Peter      FR   Paris    eesfawsd  3366552  ccccc  20020101
```

If one of your two dataframes has more lines than the other, and you want to keep all lines, add `how = 'outer'`, if you want to keep only the lines that appear in both your dataframes, add: `how = 'inner'`